# create an array out of 2 List<double>

Tags: c#, arrays, list, multidimensional-array

**UPDATE**
I tried Crazy's solution but now I have problem showing data in a foreach loop:

```
            foreach(double data in ztr.GetCurveDataForTestType())
            {
            richTextBox1.AppendText("Voltage" + data + "    ---------    ");
            richTextBox1.AppendText("Current" + data + "\r\n");
            }
```

That code prints out something like:

```
Voltage-0.175    ---------    Current-0.175  
Voltage-9.930625E-06    ---------    Current-9.930625E-06  
Voltage-0.171875    ---------    Current-0.171875  
Voltage-9.53375E-06    ---------    Current-9.53375E-06  
Voltage-0.16875    ---------    Current-0.16875
```

how should I fix it?

Hi everyone,

I have an xml file that contains Voltage and Current values for a curve. I want to draw this curve so that Voltage is X and Current as Y in the cartesian coordinate.

I can get voltage and current values out of the XML file easily like the code below. But I want to know how can I return this values in a nice clean Array that I can use easily later.

Here is my code:

```
    public double[,] GetCurveDataForTestType()
    {
        List<double> voltage = new List<double>();
        List<double> current = new List<double>();

        XPathNodeIterator volt = nav.Select("some XPATH");
        XPathNodeIterator curr = nav.Select("some XPATH");

       foreach (XPathNavigator value in volt)
       {
           voltage.Add(Convert.ToDouble(value.Value));
       }

       foreach (XPathNavigator value in curr)
       {
           current.Add(Convert.ToDouble(value.Value));
       }

        return null; //How should I reurn a nice array to use for drawing a curve(Voltage as X and current as Y)
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this...

```
   double[,] data = new double[voltage.Count(), 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < voltage.Count(); i++)
    {
        data[i, 0] = voltage[i];
        data[i, 1] = current[i];
    }
```

Comment: Thanks I will try it and report back

Comment: I tried this code but I have problem showing the result in a foreach loop. would you mind looking at my update?

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be an actual array?  .Union() can give you one list.  You could project them to an array with .Union.ToArray() if you really wanted to.

Comment: I actually cant decide in what form it will be easier to work on it for drawing a curve on XY coordinates. Thats why I need help. I just want it to be easily accessible later while drawing the curve. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

List is basicly array, you can access it by index [] so why not just use List. You also save your self the trouble of casting it.

Comment: Thanks but how can I return 2 list with one function?

Comment: @Sean87 you could return a Tuple<List<double>,List<double>>.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx

Comment: Or create class with both list and return that. That would be clean design. Personaly I feel Tuple kinda dirty. Makes your code hard to read.

Comment: Indeed.  Especially in this case where the items in the tuple are of the same type.

Answer (score 0):

To Fix your foreach loop just add indexer

```
        foreach(double data in ztr.GetCurveDataForTestType())
        {
        richTextBox1.AppendText("Voltage" + data[0] + "    ---------    ");
        richTextBox1.AppendText("Current" + data[1] + "\r\n");
        }
```